# Cant resolve issue in Flutter App using android studio

Tags: flutter

Hi I am facing this issue and some of the available answers don't resolve my issues so I post it here maybe I miss something.

[image]

Please check image in where I am facing the issue

Comment: in additional this is the error when I tried to build APK

Execution failed for task ':google_sign_in_android:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

Comment: Please describe error in details, with just image will be hard to identify what is issue.

Comment: add error details

Comment: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':google_sign_in_android:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.